# Use df.agg to run a function on my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have following DataFrame:

```
tips.head()
```

Output:

```
total_bill  tip smoker  day time    size    tip_pct
0   16.99   1.01    No  Sun Dinner  2   0.059447
1   10.34   1.66    No  Sun Dinner  3   0.160542
2   21.01   3.50    No  Sun Dinner  3   0.166587
3   23.68   3.31    No  Sun Dinner  2   0.139780
4   24.59   3.61    No  Sun Dinner  4   0.146808
```

A following function is created to sort the df based on the column "tip_pct" and output the first 3 or 6 rows.

```
def top(df, n=3, column='tip_pct'):
    return df.sort_values(by=column)[-n:]

top(tips, n=6)
```

Output:

```
total_bill  tip smoker  day time    size    tip_pct
0   16.99   1.01    No  Sun Dinner  2   0.059447
1   10.34   1.66    No  Sun Dinner  3   0.160542
2   21.01   3.50    No  Sun Dinner  3   0.166587
3   23.68   3.31    No  Sun Dinner  2   0.139780
4   24.59   3.61    No  Sun Dinner  4   0.146808
```

Next I would like an output the same as above with one difference: groupby "smoker".

```
tips.groupby('smoker').apply(top)
```

Output as screenshot:

[image]

Output as text file:

```
total_bill  tip smoker  day time    size    tip_pct
smoker                              
No  51  10.29   2.60    No  Sun Dinner  2   0.252672
149 7.51    2.00    No  Thur    Lunch   2   0.266312
232 11.61   3.39    No  Sat Dinner  2   0.291990
Yes 67  3.07    1.00    Yes Sat Dinner  1   0.325733
178 9.60    4.00    Yes Sun Dinner  2   0.416667
172 7.25    5.15    Yes Sun Dinner  2   0.710345
```

Now I would like to do the same as above but using `agg`:

```
tips.groupby('smoker').agg(top)
```

Next I get following error message, which I couldn't understand:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 2), indices imply (6, 2)
```

[image]

I couldn't understand why it doesn't work with `agg`.
What did I do wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is because [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) return aggregate values and also processing each column separately, so here cannot be used, because processing all columns of groups.